# Expected value of a lognormal distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I wonder why I couldn't compute the expected value of this function:

```
ExpectedValue[b*x*(1 + ω*x^ρ)^κ, LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ], x]
```

Comment: The documentation lists `ExpectedValue` as an outdated function. Try `Expectation` instead.

Comment: Thanks I did but its the same.

Answer (score 4):

The expression whose expectation you seek can be expanded as a power series in `x`.  (You might need to worry about whether this converges).

```
expr = b*x*(1 + ω*x^ρ)^κ;
coeff = Assuming[κ > 0 && n >= 0, 
   SeriesCoefficient[expr /. x^ρ -> z, {z, 0, n}]];
```

We see that the power series converges to your original expression.

```
Sum[coeff x^(ρ n), {n, 0, ∞}] == expr
(* True *)
```

We can take the expectation of a general term in this series

```
expectation = 
  FullSimplify[
   Expectation[coeff x^(ρ n), 
    x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]]];
```

You can them sum the series to obtain the expectation.

```
Sum[expectation, {n, 0, ∞}] // InputForm
(* Sum[b*E^(((1 + n*ρ)*(2*μ + (1 + n*ρ)*σ^2))/2)*ω^n*Binomial[κ, n], 
 {n, 0, Infinity}] *)
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica doesn't return a simple expression for this sum, but you might find for the parameter values of interest it converges quite quickly.

Answer (score 3):

The function is [`Expectation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html) not `ExpectedValue`.  Unfortunately,

```
Expectation[b*x*(1 + ω*x^ρ)^κ, x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]]
```

does not yield an answer.

If `κ` is an integer, it does appear to work:

```
Expectation[b*x*(1 + ω*x^ρ)^3, x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]]
(* b E^(μ + σ^2/2) (1 + 3 E^(μ ρ + 1/2 ρ (2 + ρ) σ^2) ω + 
   3 E^(2 ρ (μ + (1 + ρ) σ^2)) ω^2 + E^(3/2 ρ (2 μ + (2 + 3 ρ) σ^2)) ω^3) *)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. But I I have _κ_ as a parameter that could take any value both integer and non-integer. May be there are some alternative to compute that?

Comment: If you don't need an explicit formula (which might be impossible to get), you can use `NExpectation` for numerical values of your parameters.

Comment: @YosephGetachew - Do you know any constraints on {b, ω, ρ, κ}?

Comment: I think that your expression might be written as a power series in `x`. You could then find the expectation of each term. Perhaps a small number of terms might be sufficient.

Comment: @Chris. Thanks if that is the only option I have then I would reformulate the problem.

Comment: @Bob - But the values of the parameters do not matter because all work except when _k_ is a fraction, which is the case in the model.

Comment: @mikado - Thanks but I don't exactly understand what you mean.

Comment: @YosephGetachew - As a general rule, the more constraints there are on the parameters/variables, the easier it is to solve problems. Since you indicated that you did not want to constrain `κ` to be an integer, the alternative is to hope for constraints on the other parameters. If any exist (e.g., positive, nonnegative), then they should be provided to Mathematica to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know you want the expectation for any positive value of $\kappa$ but here is the resulting expectation for integer values of $\kappa$:

```
mean[κ_, b_, μ_, σ_, ρ_, ω_] := b Exp[μ + σ^2/2] *
  Sum[Binomial[κ, i] ω^i Exp[i ρ (μ + (1 + i ρ/2) σ^2)],
  {i, 0, κ}]
```

For example,

```
mean[4, b, μ, σ, ρ, ω]
```

$$b e^{\mu +\frac{\sigma ^2}{2}} \left(\omega ^4 e^{4 \rho  \left(\mu +(2 \rho +1) \sigma ^2\right)}+4 \omega ^3 e^{3 \rho  \left(\mu +\left(\frac{3 \rho }{2}+1\right) \sigma ^2\right)}+6 \omega ^2 e^{2 \rho  \left(\mu +(\rho +1) \sigma ^2\right)}+4 \omega  e^{\rho  \left(\mu +\left(\frac{\rho }{2}+1\right) \sigma ^2\right)}+1\right)$$

As a partial check on that formula:

```
d = TransformedDistribution[b*x*(1 + ω*x^ρ)^κ, x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ],
   Assumptions -> {b > 0, w ∈ Reals, ρ > 0, κ >= 1}];
ExpandAll[mean[#, b, μ, σ, ρ, ω] - Mean[d /. κ -> #]] & /@ Range[6]
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: Thanks @JimB! But the parameter _k_ is non-integer. The problem is that it only works when it is polynomial. I know I could get a solution for it if I can get a solution for _Expectation[Log[1 + x], 
 x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]]_.

Comment: You're very optimistic.  *Mathematica* does not return a solution for `Expectation[Log[1 + z], 
 z \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 
 Assumptions -> \[Sigma] > 0]` so I don't know why you think there would be a closed-form solution for your original random variable when $\kappa$ is not an integer.

Comment: You are right. I think I have to do it numerically. But you give it a good try with your Taylor series expansion. Thanks.